# HTTPS Certificate for internal use

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

I'm setting up a webserver for a system that needs to be used **only** through HTTPS, on an **internal network** (no access from outside world)

Right now I got it setup with a self-signed certificate, and it works fine, except for a nasty warning that all browsers fire up, as the CA authority used to sign it is naturally not trusted.

Access is provided by a local DNS domain name resolved on local DNS server (example: https://myapp.local/), that maps that address to 192.168.x.y

Is there some provider that can issue me a proper certificate for use on an internal domain name (myapp.local)? Or is my only option to use a FQDN on a real domain, and later map it to a local IP address?

**Note**: I would like an option where it's not needed to mark the server public key as trusted on each browser, as I have not control over workstations.

Comment: Interesting question! I don't have a real answer, but I would hope that a "real" CA would not issue a certificate bound to a name that is not somehow globally unique. A FQDN, by virtue of its global namespace, or a publicly-routable IP address are okay, but a private name could be spoofed.

Comment: After a long search I finally managed to create SSL certificate for my local network.


Please check my detailed answer in this [post][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150089/is-there-a-way-to-have-https-for-local-network-webapps-without-buying-any-domain/73013303#73013303

Comment: Please check my answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150089/is-there-a-way-to-have-https-for-local-network-webapps-without-buying-any-domain/73013303#73013303 you can create whatevever domain you want and create SSL for it without any access to Internet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did the following, which worked nicely for me:

I got a wildcard SSL cert for *.mydomain.com (Namecheap, for example, provide this cheaply)

I created a CNAME DNS record pointing "mybox.mydomain.com" at "mybox.local".

I hope that helps - unfortunately you'll have the expense of a wildcard cert for your domain name, but you may already have that.

Comment: I have a question for you. This approach is working even for subdomain of your mybox, like www.mybox.local, mobile.mybox.local, api,mybox.local? I mean, I have just to setup a single CNAME DNS record ponting to mybox.local to enable ssl on all the subdomains for the mybox.local? Because I have a Docker container running Apache with several websites and I would like to use with HTTPS the mybox.local approach that I'm already using for HTTP.

Comment: @noun sorry, I don't think this approach would work for a subdomain. In fact, after further investigation most DNS servers won't return .local address (that only seems to work for LAN lookups, e.g. from a home router). In the end, I just had to add a normal A record with the LAN IP address in it (e.g. 192.168.1.123) and that worked fine.

Comment: Thank you, that what I have thought.

Comment: @paul May you explain your setup a little bit further? As far as I know, SSL certificates have to be renewed regularly (e.g. every 90 days with _Let's Encrypt_). Without access to the "outside world"/internet, that's not possible, right? Or is there an other way to achieve persistent and secure SSL/TLS connections between devices in a local network?

Comment: @Candor Yes, the SSL certs I use also have to be renewed (yearly for the paid wildcard cert I use). I don't think it's possible to renew Letsencrypt certs (or any certs that will be accepted by browsers) without external access. If you are only working between local network devices, self-signed certs should be fine,

Comment: @paul You're right, self-signed certs are totally sufficient for internal testing/experimenting (what I'm doing right now), I just wondered if there is a way to use official CAs in order to prevent those big red browser warnings, so the application gets way more user friendly. Thanks! EDIT: Here's a discussion about a similar situation: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificates-for-hosts-on-private-networks/174/35

Comment: @PaulHiggins, could please tell how did you get SSL certificate? I meant did you get self-signed or not? if not, does it possible to self-signed

Comment: @HosseinVatani maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676662/4773888 ; Or basically boiled down it's: (is this page accessible to the public?) If no, use a self signed cert. If yes, use a cert from letsencrypt.org, they're gratis. (Are you a bank or otherwise an agency that benefiets from being more thrououtly verified) Buy yourself an SSl cert which includes more identitiy approval besides domain ownsership. verisign.com is one of these companys. These certs cost multiple thousand dollars but for banks and such they're very much worth it.

Answer (score 29):

You have two practical options:

1. Stand up your own CA.  You can do it with OpenSSL and there's a lot of Google info out there.
2. Keep using your self-signed cert, but add the public key to your trusted certs in the browser.  If you're in an Active Directory domain, this can be done automatically with group policy.

Comment: Your options seem to be in reverse order, as you should only start your own CA if manually adding isn't an option. (Otherwise it seems like using a 16 ton bulldozer to get groceries)

Comment: This seems like the proper way to do it, but I would like an option where it's not needed to mark the PK as trusted on each browser, as I have not control over all workstations. I will add this as note to question.

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to ask the typical cert people for that. For ease of use I'd get with the FQDN though, you might use a subdomain to your already registered one: https://mybox.example.com

Also you might want to look at wildcard certificates, providing a blanket cert for (e.g.) https://*.example.com/ - even usable for virtual hosting, should you need more than just this one cert.

Certifying sub- or sub-sub domains of FQDN *should* be standard business - maybe not for the point&click big guys that proud themselves to provide the certificates in just 2 minutes.

In short: To make the cert trusted by a workstation you'd have to either

- change settings on the workstations (which you don't want) or
- use an already trusted party to sign your key (which you're looking for a way around).

That's *all* your choices. Choose your poison.

Answer (score 6):

*I would have added this as a comment but it was a bit long..*

This is not really an answer to your questions, but in practice I've found that it's not recommended to use a .local domain - even if it's on your "local" testing environment, with your own DNS Server.

I know that Active Directory uses the .local name by default when your install DNS, but even people at Microsoft say to avoid it.

If you have control over the DNS Server you can use a .com, .net, or .org domain - even if it's internal and private only. This way, you could actually buy the domain name that you are using internally and then buy a certificate for that domain name and apply it to your local domain.

Comment: The .local domain means it will be looked up using mDNS, so anyone on the network can "register" any .local domain. That's probably the reason some people recommend not using it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement, have our companys browsers trust our internal websites.

I didnt want our public DNS to issue public DNS for our internal sites, so the only way to make this work that I found was to use an internal CA.

Heres the writeup for this,

https://medium.com/@mike.reider/getting-firefox-chrome-to-trust-your-internal-websites-internal-certificate-authority-a53ba2d4c2af

Answer (score 1):

#### Development purpose only

This docker image solves the problem (thanks to local-ip.co): https://github.com/medic/nginx-local-ip.

It launches a reverse proxy in the port 443 with a public cert that works with any `*.my.local-ip.co` domain. Eg. your local IP is 192.168.10.10 → **192-168-10-10.my.local-ip.co** already points to it (it's a public domain)! Assuming the app is running in your computer at the port 8080, you only need to execute this to proxy pass your app and expose it at the URL https://192-168-10-10.my.local-ip.co:

```
$ APP_URL=http://192.168.10.10:8080 docker-compose up
```

The domain is resolved with any public DNS you have configured in the devices where you want to access the app, but your traffic keeps local between your app and the client (through the proxy), so you can even use it to connect with devices within the same LAN network, without any of the traffic going out to internet, all the traffic is local.

The reason that is mostly useful for development is that anybody can launch an application with this same certificate, so is not really secure, but helpful when you need to expose your app with HTTPS while developing or testing (e.g. HTML5 apps in Android that are loaded with Webview).

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer is NO.

out-of-the-box, browsers won't trust certificates unless it's ultimately been verified by someone pre-programmed into the browser, e.g. verisign, register.com.

you can only get a verified certificate for a globally unique domain.

so i'd suggest instead of myapp.local you use myapp.local.yourcompany.com, for which you should be able to get a certificate, provided you own yourcompany.com.  it'll cost you thought, several hundred per year.

also be warned wildcard certificates might only go down to one level -- so you could use it for a.yourcompany.com and local.yourcompany.com but maybe not b.a.yourcompany.com or myapp.local.yourcompany.com, unless you pay more.

(does anyone know, does it depend on the type of wildcard certificate?  are sub-sub-domains trusted by the major browsers?)

Comment: So what if you domain is globally unique? I created a subdomain, pointed it at 192.168.1.2 ... It does not seem to work. Why not? The server at 192.168.1.2 sees the subdomain resolved to itself, right?