# Encrypting http messages in ASP.NET in local net

Tags: asp.net, http, encryption

I'm working on web site on ASP .NET Core that will be hosted locally and I need to encrypt messages between client and server.
What are the ways to do it?
I know I can create self-signed certificate but as far as I understand clients' computers will always warn that site is not safe.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: If this is all in a LAN, you can just install the certificate on the participating computers. Or use @trailmax suggestion, assuming you use a domain and it's accessible through the internet.

Comment: @trailmax As far as I know it is not advisable to get HTTPS certificate for local domains.

Comment: @ettudagny Have a look on this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984945/809357